# Slider link to change not joining

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, slider

I have a slider that has links at the bottom that would like to change the slides when clicked. Have the "active" class working on both elements, Can't join them together.

Links just have a #LINK_NAME prefix

Jquery code is:

```
var $slider = $('.home-slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 5000; // 5 seconds

jQuery(function ($) {
    slides().fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    $('.nav-slider a').first().addClass('active');

    slides().first().fadeIn(100);

    // auto scroll
    $interval = setInterval(sliderInterval, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);

    $('.home-slider').hover(function () {
        $interval = clearInterval($interval);
    }, function () {
        $interval = setInterval(sliderInterval, $time_between_slides);
    });
});

function slides() {
    return $slider.find($slide);
}

function sliderInterval() {
    var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

    slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-slider a').eq($i).removeClass('active');

    slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);
    $('.nav-slider a').eq($i+1).addClass('active');

    if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

    slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
    slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
}
// Handles navigation for each slide (placed in the nav div)
$('.nav-slider a').click(function() {
   $('.nav-slider a').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4EU9/

Comment: Consider modifying the Bootstrap Carousel example for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need, find the index of the clicked link then use it to search the elements in your slider

```
$('.nav-slider a').click(function() {
   $('.nav-slider a').removeClass("active");
   $('.home-slider').find('.active').removeClass("active");

   $('.home-slider').find('li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').addClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Updated js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/k4EU9/1/

All you need to do is add your display:list-item, you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks Michael - Much appreciated, will dissect so I can understand rather than just copy and paste.

Comment: Sorry Michael - tried to implement the display:list-item and the link when clicked doesn't change the slide.

Comment: Show me your fiddle and I will have a look for you

Comment: ha ha - doesn't sound dirty at all :-) here it is in it's current state - I thought I could just call slides() inside the function after it had updated the current slide. http://jsfiddle.net/ev8Qc/

Comment: So the way you have done it will not work, as you are essentially asking it to just find $('li');

Comment: Basically, you could retrigger your slider interval function, then just make sure you fadeOut the current slide. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ev8Qc/1/

Comment: ok so retriggering the slider interval pulls the slide in and the fade out removes the slide from view so the new slide can take its place. why is it pulling the next slide over rather than the one thats been clicked. is it something to do with the var $1?

Comment: Yes, you are basically doing the transitioning on the next element along, one way around this is just to change your click function to add active on the element before the one you have clicked. i.e. $(this).index() - 1